# Multiple inheritance with constructor arguments

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I'm not quite sure how should it be written correctly. Can anyone help please?

```
class A {
public:
    A(int x);
};

class B {
public:
    B(float y);
};

class Launcher : public A, public B
{
    Launcher() : A(int x), B(float y); // ?
};

int main()
{
    Launcher(1, true);
}
```

Comment: What you have is close. You just need empty braces rather than a semicolon on your `Launcher` constructor. Oh, and remove the types in that line. So `Launcher() : A(x), B(y) {}`

Comment: You have to explicitly list the parameters of the derived class constructor, it's not necessary that they pass through one-for-one, all kinds of computation can be done along the way.  All of these are possible:

    `Launcher(int x, float y) : A(x), B(y) {}`
    `Launcher(int x) : A(x), B(x * 0.2f) {}`
    `Launcher() : A(7), B(42.0f) {}`
    `Launcher(std::pair<int, float> p) : A(1 << p.first), B(std::sqrt(p.second)) {}`

Comment: @FredLarson But then what would the values of `x` and `y` be?

Comment: Oops, your constructor needs to accept the parameters: `Launcher(int x, float y) : A(x), B(y) {}`

Comment: @Ben Voigt works like magic. Thank you!

Comment: I honestly tried to google it out, but probably haven't managed to formulate the query correctly.